# Looping in bash for preparing awk's input statement

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to parse some nginx logs by date. I have written an awk oneliner to find all matching logs for a day, like:

```
awk '/05\/May\/2012/ { print $0;}' /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

What I want to do is to loop over some days and months using bash. Here is what I have got

```
#!/bin/bash

for h in 2012
do
    for i in Apr May
    do
        for j in 01 02 03 04 05
        do
            echo "/${j}\/${i}\/${h}/"
            search_string="'/${j}\/${i}\/${h}/ { print \$0;}'"
            echo $search_string;
            awk $search_string /var/log/nginx/access.log  
            echo "${h} ${i} ${j} done" 
        done
    done
done
```

However, this fails on awk line with:

```
 awk: 1: unexpected character '''
```

It seems like I need to escape some variables, but I haven't found a solution so far.

Comment: print $0 is not needed because it is the default action.

Comment: Why not write the whole thing in AWK?

Comment: Note that awk does not do anything special with quotes -- quotes (single and double) are a shell mechanism to group words together as a unit.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I thought of that too, or even using perl. With awk however, I am not too comfortable, I just use it in a very line oriented way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes are not needed.
Double quotes are needed.

```
search_string="/${j}\/${i}\/${h}/ { print \$0;}"
awk "$search_string" /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

Answer (score 6):

It's better to use awk's variable assignment feature to pass the shell variable into awk. Then use `~` to match the pattern. For example:

```
search_string="$j/$i/$h"
awk -v pattern="${search_string}" '$0 ~ pattern {print $0}' /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

This is the recommended method specified in the [awk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-Shell-Variables.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here is your entire script in one AWK script:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
         years = "2012"
         months = "Apr|May"
         days = "01|02|03|04|05"
     }
     $0 ~ days "/" months "/" years {
         print
     }' /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

If you need the start and done markers, those can be added.